# How do I configure the gnome panel from a script?

Tags: gnome-panel, gnome-classic, gconf

I can easily set the number of workspaces and the workspace names with the gconftool-2, as follows:

```
  gconftool-2 --type int --set /apps/metacity/general/num_workspaces 4
  gconftool-2 --type string --set /apps/metacity/workspace_names/name_1 Dev
  gconftool-2 --type string --set /apps/metacity/workspace_names/name_2 Docs
  gconftool-2 --type string --set /apps/metacity/workspace_names/name_3 VM
  gconftool-2 --type string --set /apps/metacity/workspace_names/name_4 Web
```

However, for some reason I am unable to use similar techniques to set the number of rows in the workspace switcher, or set the preference to show workspace names.  I am similarly unable to add applets and launchers via gconftool.  *I would also like to be able to configure my system to have just one panel at the bottom of the screen. (Solved this much)*

I have reviewed the [using gconf](http://library.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/gconf-0.html.en) page without success.  For some options, I have been successfully able to find the option name by dumping `gconftool-2 -R /` to a file, change the option via the GUI, and then dump again and diff. This technique was not fruitful with the above mentioned items.  I have also tried [--dump and --load](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31923/gnome-panel-sync-between-different-systems), and have tried restarting gnome-panel and gconfd-2, but that does not help either.  Is there some other mechanism besides gconftool-2 that the panel uses for storing settings?

I am currently using 11.10 in gnome-classic mode.

**Update:** Found a [script to hide panels](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19136/hide-the-gnome-panel-on-one-of-the-workspaces).

**Update 2:** An easier way to remove the top panel:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-panel.layout toplevel-id-list "['bottom-panel']"
```

---

I actually still cannot configure the panel with dconf.

I can change an existing panel item to point to a different program via `dconf write /org/gnome/gnome-panel/layout/objects/object-6/instance-config/location "'...'"`, but `killall -HUP gnome-panel` is also required.

If I try to remove an item from the panel via `dconf write /org/gnome/gnome-panel/layout/objects/object-id-list "[...]"`, the contents of the panel do not change, even after restarting gnome panel.

If I make the same change with dconf-editor, it changes immediately.

What do I need to do to update the panel after dconf write?

(Note: behaves the same way under 12.04)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although `gsettings` cannot change schemaless keys in dconf, `dconf` can. You do not need to write your own program. What you can do to change the number of rows in the workspace switcher is:

1. install the `dconf-tool` package
2. run `dconf` as

> dconf write /org/gnome/gnome-panel/layout/objects/workspace-switcher/instance-config/num-rows 2
>   
>   You can play with lots of other gnome-panel entries with `dconf-editor` as well.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that some gnome preferences are stored in gconf, and may be edited via gconftool-2, while others are stored in dconf, which may be edited via gesttings.  See: [How do I change dconf keys without a gui](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72070/how-do-i-change-dconf-keys-without-a-gui-for-a-post-install-script).

**Update:** Unfortunately, I quickly ran into the problem described in this bug report: [no way to set a schemaless key using gsettings](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=648009).  Many of the preferences that I want to set are schemaless keys stored in the binary file ~/.config/dconf/user, and it seems there is no way to edit these short of via the internal dconf APIs -- so you'd have to write a C program to do it.